# how to use trello api client.js with jsfiddle.net

Tags: api, jsfiddle, trello

I have started learning trello api and trying a trello api client.js and developing basic application based on example given on trello.com. I pasted code on following link 
`http://jsfiddle.net/Ezyw4/2/` it is not working. Is there any mistake in my code. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This issue is specific to JSFiddle.  It isn't loading client.js at all, because it doesn't know what kind of resource it is.

You've referenced

`https://api.trello.com/1/client.js?key=yourapikey`

... and **because there is no extension at the very end of the URL**, JSFiddle doesn't know what kind of resource it is.

From [the JSFiddle docs](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#add-resources):

> **Warning:** jsFiddle is recognizing the type of the resource by the
>   extension. If you want to use a dynamic resource please add a dummy
>   GET variable i.e.
>   http://example.com/download/js/dynamically.js?somevar=somevalue&dummy=.js.
>   This will trick jsFiddle to recognize it as JavaScript resource.

You can solve this by appending `&dummy=.js` to the end of your managed resource URL, i.e.

```
https://api.trello.com/1/client.js?key=yourapikey&dummy=.js
```